# Malicious user inflicting XSS attacks appears to be on my own network

Tags: web-application, web-browser, ip, vulnerability

I have a live Django project where I'm using nginx as a reverse proxy with gunicorn as the application server. It's a fairly new project and isn't SSL enabled yet. There's a user on this project who's been inflicting XSS attacks and stealing user cookies. I went through my session data to find out this user's IP address. It turned out his IP is similar to 10.*.*.* - i.e. *he's on my own network*? All other users appear to have normal public IP addresses BTW.

I was originally hoping to find out his IP and deny it in my nginx conf. But I suppose it's not a robust solution given he's appearing to be on my own network. Are there any ways I can block this person's network requests while I try to figure out how to stop his XSS attacks where he's logging in as other users?

Comment: Do you collect the session data on the application server? In that case all connections will appear with the same IP address: the LAN IP of the reverse proxy. If you want to know the real IP address, you need to check on nginx, not on gunicorn.

Comment: Okay, going to do that. I was checking at session data on the application server indeed. But it's still true that most users still appear to have regular public IP addresses.

Comment: First step - You will need to identify which machine or device which has the `10.x.x.x` address. How big is your network? Is it hosted internally or at an ISP or cloud? I'm wondering why another, unknown, machine is on your private network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask your network administrator about who that IP address belongs to, then pay them a visit and firmly apply a [LART](http://catb.org/jargon/html/L/LART.html) to the back of their head.

Should that not be an option, configure nginx to only allow connections from your own IP address. This is obviously only a good idea when your IP address is static, because otherwise you will lock yourself out when your IP changes.

Another stop-gap measure is to reconfigure nginx to require HTTP authentication for all requests. That way a user can only make *any* requests by providing username and password or even better with the correct certificate.

How to do this is a technical question for https://serverfault.com

Comment: Applying a LART isn't an option because this is a one person project - I do everything myself, including being an accidental network admin.

Comment: @SarahMicj Does that mean there should not be anyone but you on that 10.x network? Then it seems like you have a far larger problem to worry about...

Comment: Yes that's what I'm thinking

Answer (score 1):

There are some things you can do about this. In general you can write code that does not allow an attacker to perform XSS attacks. Of cause it might take some time to fix it.

The next thing you can do is ***adding a HIDS to your server*** to prevent such attacks in general. Of cause this is not a 100% solution but it will reduce the risk. I use [OSSEC](http://ossec.github.io/) for example. Its Open Source and won't cost you anything.

Also I would consider that this is not done by one of your employees but by an ***external attacker that somehow gained access to your network***.